# Problems trying to upload a file clicking on an image

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file, upload

So I tried to make an upload file input open when I clicked on a input type image. When I click the image the upload file window comes up, but when I choose a file, it doesn't load (the name doesn't appear instead of "no file chosen"). Also, if there's information on the form and the image button is clicked the previous inputs are emptied.

Everything works fine when I click in upload file instead of the image, nothing is emptied and the image loads properly. Here's the code, hope you can help me:

HTML form:

```
        <form class='register-form-user-frmt' action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <span class='register-form-user-email'> 
                E-mail: <br> <input type='email' name='register-form-user-email' />
            </span>
            <span class='register-form-user-name'> 
                On-page name: <br> <input type='text' name='register-form-user-name' />
            </span>
            <span class='register-form-user-password'> 
                Password: <br> <input type='password' name='register-form-user-password' />
            </span>
            <span class='register-form-user-password-repeat'> 
                Check password: <br> <input type='password' name='register-form-user-password-repeat' />
            </span>
            <span class='register-form-user-image-upload-hidden'> 
                <input type='file' id='register-form-user-image-upload-hidden' name='photo'/>
            </span>
            <span class='register-form-user-submit'> 
                <input type='submit' name='register-form-user-submit' value='Submit' />
            </span>
            <span class='register-form-user-image-button'> 
                Upload image: <br> <input type='image' name='register-form-user-image-user-button' src='images/camera upload logo.png' />
            </span>
        </form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.register-form-user-image-button').click(function() {
    $('#register-form-user-image-upload-hidden').click();
});
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
<span class='register-form-user-image-button'> 
    Upload image: <br> <input type='file' name='register-form-user-image-user-button' src='images/camera upload logo.png' />
</span>
```

After this, create php file to filter if your file type is jpg, bmp, etc. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) is the reference. This will work without jquery.

Comment: Nope, the "upload file" button looks the same.